# This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'T[keyof T]' and 'string' have no overlap

Tags: typescript

I have the following fn in JS, basically I want to find an object in an array by its key.

I receive the following error:

This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'T[keyof T]' and 'string' have no overlap

Any ideas how to solve it?

```
   export const findObjectByKey = <T>(
      prop: keyof T,
      value: string,
      data: ReadonlyArray<T>
    ) => data.find((x) => x[prop] === value);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can tell TypeScript what the value of `value` is by declaring a type for `prop` (traditionally `K`) that extends `keyof T`:

```
export const findObjectByKey = <T, K extends keyof T>(
    prop: K,
    value: T[K],
    data: ReadonlyArray<T>
) => data.find((x) => x[prop] === value);
```

Now TypeScript knows that the comparison is okay (and it works for properties whose type isn't `string`, though you may not need that right now):

```
// Works, `obj.foo` is string
findObjectByKey("foo", "x", [{ foo: "y" }])
// Works, `obj[42]` is string
findObjectByKey(42, "x", ["1"])
// Works, `obj.foo` is number
findObjectByKey("foo", 42, [{ foo: 27, bar: "x" }])
// Error as desired, `obj.foo` is number but `value` is string
findObjectByKey("foo", "x", [{ foo: 27, bar: "x" }])
//                     ^−−−−− Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wGYEtkBMDyARgFbAIwBCAngNLBVwC8cAPACoB8AFAFBz9wwUCGABccANb0IGOGwA0fAQDcAhgBsArsHFsA2lKoy5AXUUC4uVTFXiASsFW4U6qgEEoUVVXYceASiYOS2tVADpsPC4uEEDGYJA9IRETJkZmNS1gfwBuHh5IghIySlp6LgAiDAgICvk4CpA6uD0Ab2qIcQqARgqAXxN-Apwi0nJqOipKjuaAFgAmeraO8XmAdgGhwqIx0smuBfrG5r0eisGeIA)

Major thanks to [Aleksey L.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1113002/aleksey-l) for pointing out we could do better than just a union of the types of the property values.

Comment: To tighten the `value` type we can introduce generic type parameter for property as well https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wGYEtkBMDyARgFbAIwBCAngNLBVwC8cAPACoA0cNcoMweVHADW9CBjhsAfAAoAUHEVwwUCGABc3DgqUA3AIYAbAK7BNbANo0AutqVxc+mPs0AlYPtwpDVAIJQofSp2KTkASiYpByd9ADpsPBkZEAjGKJALFTVrJkZmAxNgMIBuOTkEghIySlp6GQAiDAgIeq56kFa4CwBvOCaITXqARnq4AF9rMPKcStJyajoqBv7OgBYAJi4evubNdYB2ccnpvCI5msWZDbaOreH646A

Comment: Thanks @AlekseyL.! I *thought* it was possible but... Do you want to post an answer, or do you want me to edit the above?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use another generic to indicate that the `prop`'s associated value on T is a string, so that `x[prop]` is permitted:

```
export const findObjectByKey = <P extends keyof any, T extends Record<P, string>>(
  prop: P,
  value: string,
  data: ReadonlyArray<T>
) => data.find((x) => x[prop] === value);

findObjectByKey('foo', 'val', [{ foo: 'val', bar: 'bar' }])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following, basically you need to to say to TS to type `value` based on the types of prop in `T`.

```
export const findObjectByKey = <T>(
  prop: keyof T,
  value: T[typeof prop],
  data: ReadonlyArray<T>
) => data.find((x) => x[prop] === value)
```

[Play ground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigJQgQwBM0AbEAHgG8AoKKVPAWwgC4pFh4BLVAcwG4abAK7x6TVuy68BtPDxZ0hDAEYIqAXwB8AqqEhQAInmB5MOfEVSkAgvHh5ycJGm1UqAYzTsoBY3lZGJmYA2oIUdIwKAOR4UQA0wqKRrFHK8VByLAAsAAxQ6nFhEeJQUe7piCJi0QTpmawATACs%20YW04dUpEBVVyaUAZnXyrACMeQVUALo6-UKo7sCcaFD93AQA8soAVhALAEIgANIQ5AAqmlAAFIIA1iesdyDI-VCnbVAAbnjEQgqnwXoIM8oI9Ju9fCZWLhCCQQLZ7GdNFQAJRQcKCeAQYBVHx%20AB0q1QBEulwAHqiMBdScFQZgMFgvj8IMiNG5PKhvPARmZCRttrtgAdjo4EChUJpLjF5OlcgkIXhkQJ2ZyGjy1psdvsjicyE4xRKotV0mV0vLFWyvMhiBA8e5rXh4JcWcqrTbiMgeJcuc7Lda8e7PfAGiygA)