# Typescript: "This condition will always return 'false'" when accessing class instance property

Tags: javascript, typescript

Example code:

```
class Base {}

function fn<T extends typeof Base>(
    Cls: T,
    prop: keyof InstanceType<T>,
) {
    const instance = new Cls() as InstanceType<T>;
    return instance[prop] === 'foo';
}
```

TS Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8C+AodAzArgO2ABcBLAez2izwB4AVaBAD0ITwBMZCBPABwVKxxEAPgAU6aJOgBhEBABc0WgBoJUngCdSPRQGsEXAdACSeCITAEEtXgjrDVAShRrJwcuejEzFq9AC80HgIAO4ycqLOkCY+lsDWtvYA3K7QGgiEOBoU3uZxCADamtoAugH+gQDkWKSklSkYQA

I'm getting "This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'InstanceType[keyof InstanceType]' and 'string' have no overlap."

However, it's possible that the condition returns true. How can I fix this?

Comment: This may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67173389/this-condition-will-always-return-false-since-the-types-tkeyof-t-and-stri?rq=1

Comment: The answers in the other question is suggesting `'foo' as unknown as InstanceType<T>[keyof InstanceType<T>]`? This isn't what I want, since it's essentially the same as `@ts-ignore`. I know `instance[prop]` can be a string and I want to compare it with a string.

Comment: @LeoJiang what do you think about my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, typescript cannot guarantee that all the properties from that type that extends `BaseClass` will be of type `string` (you are doing a comparison with a string value). If you don't care, you can just cast it to a string and loose the type safety (eg: `return instance[prop] as never as string === 'foo'`). Otherwise:

1. You can enforce the key to only be of a string member:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQ0PQC4IlgjNALzQDkkAJqQNzqY54BMx0+jAzLZtrluy5zoYGWACwtyEKrQC+qVFgCeAByQBlLACcAlgDsA5gAVNAe2UQAPABUAfCzTcA2gGtoe6M4SKTAM2hWAXQAuaDwdA2gEAA8cXQoYKxcA6AB+D2gQ3QQANwRNVBkXL19-ANpUHwBXXWAsbRNdaB9da0iYhDiYJVUS+AgEABpoAGk22PjoDXCjU3MLAEldPDAahCsVBGsbbYAKIWgAYRAIEKsB-eVZkOHzgEoUfeAGvDclrBXgJBIsgHdD45290g0EWy1W61UWy4mE0CCwlU0jT0YM+jkuZmSRCxZEoNAK8maOz6gzIInwpFu1GgAHpqdgABbaGA-EyaZwQCq6ImIIakESMClU2kMplNMDaY6oIA

```
class Base {
    test1 = 'asd';
    test2 = 123;
    test3 = 3;
    test4 = 'asd';
}

type StringProps<T> = {
    [k in keyof T]: string extends T[k] ? k : never
}[keyof T];

function fn<T extends typeof Base, K extends StringProps<InstanceType<T>>>(
    Cls: T,
    prop: K,
) {
    const instance = new Cls() as InstanceType<T>;
    return instance[prop] === 'asd';
}

fn(Base, 'test1'); // this works
fn(Base, 'test2'); // this fails
```

2. Or you can make it more generic and pass the predicate as a parameter to your function:

```
class Base {
    test1 = 'asd';
    test2 = 123;
}

function fn<T extends typeof Base, K extends keyof InstanceType<T>>(
    Cls: T,
    prop: K,
    validate: (value: InstanceType<T>[K]) => boolean,
) {
    const instance = new Cls() as InstanceType<T>;
    return validate(instance[prop]);
}

fn(Base, 'test2', v => v === 456);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work because now `fn` only works on a subset of the props (only the string props). I need it to work with any prop. Oddly, changing it to `typeof instance[prop] === 'string' && instance[prop] === 'foo'` doesn't work either.

Comment: @LeoJiang I personally think having a subset of only the string props provides better compile time type safety. But it should work how you want it if you assign it locally: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQBfVqBmBXAdsAC4CWA9vtNvgDwAq0CAHkQvgCYxECeADgmWxxEAPgAUqaFOgBhEBABc0OgBpJ03gCcyvJQGsE3QdACS+CETCEEdPgnoi1AShTqpwCheglzl69ABeaHwEAHdZeTEXSFNfK2AbOwcAbjdoD19oADcwEFwkIJ8LeIQAbS0dAF1U6WhNBCJcTUoefmMcvIKAoIByC00fAHMe6AAyUezc-MDu6B7sMjIe1PQgA